# Optimize checking attribute of each class instance inside a list

Tags: python, optimization, attributes

Let's say I have a simple class, with an attribute, `x`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(-5, 5) # not the most efficient, but it serves purposes well
```

I'll also have a list, with hundreds of instances of this class:

```
Az = []
for i in range(150):
    Az.append(A())
```

Now, let's say I want to loop through all the `A`s in `Az`, and run a function on the classes who's `x` attribute is equivalent to less than one. This is one way, but alas, is very inefficient:

```
for cls in Az:
    if cls.x<1:
        func1(cls) # A random function that accepts a class as a parameter, and does something to it
```

So, to wrap it up, my question: How to optimize the speed of the checking?

Comment: Why do you think you can optimize it further? If you make it a pandas dataframe you might be able to parallelize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimizing only the third step is tricky. Why not start at the second step by saving list ids of classes where attribute x is <1?

```
Az = []
ids = []
for i, id in enumerate(range(150)):
    cls = A()
    if cls.x < 1:
        ids.append(id)
    Az.append(cls)
```

And then modify the third step:

```
for id in ids:
    func1(Az[id])
```

Comment: Thank you. But, while it may be tricky, is it still possible to optimize only the third part? Because I'm using this in a video game, and the main loop is constantly changing these attributes, which means a static list won't really suit my purposes.